# Xcode never finishes building and uses up memory on computer

Tags: xcode

I’m trying to build my Swift app and, as the title states, it never finishes building and eventually I get a warning for critically low system memory. I have about 23GB free on my computer but as soon as I hit build and watch the memory usage on Activity Monitor the Swift process gradually increases in size, reaching tens of gigabytes in size until my computer dies. This only recently started happening but I don’t know how to solve it. It also seems to happen whilst Xcode indexes my project. It gets stuck at the "Compiling Swift sources" stage. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! The problem was I had a function that was a bit complex and it was returning a value, but I had set the function as `void`. I tracked this down by removing files that I'd recently changed from the target and then compiling to see if it would give an error or just compile forever. Then I commented out bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by cleaning the code first (shift+command+K)...
Then keep it free for indexing...
After that rebuild (command+B)...
And it works fine...